# Get list with values from database with Entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using SQL server 2015 and the newest verion of Entity Framework. I made an Entity data model for my application. I need to get lists that I made in my database.

This is my table structure:
[image]

And this happens when I want to query and find all the words that belong to a certain list

```
select contentwords.word 
from ContentWords 
inner join content 
  on ContentWords.ContentWordsId=content.ContentWordsId 
where content.ListId in (select listid 
                         from List 
                         where name='BlackListPageWords')
```

I get this as an result:

[image]

I want to have this result in my application. How do I get these results and put in a list so I can use it in my application?

Comment: Are you not using DBSets?

Comment: @KidCode I am not sure. All I know that I added an item called ADO.NET Entity Data Model. Sorry I am a nooby:)

Comment: You need to show some sample code. What have you tried so far? Have you created a Database context in your code? Have you tried running the query against that?

Comment: This may be can help you, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj205424.aspx